# How can I use Substring and Replace in one SQL-Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, substring

```
SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(name, '*Deleted*', '' )  FROM OBJ_R) AS lastname and
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN NAME)-1) FROM OBJ_R
```

instead of 
*Deleted* Beyeler, Nicole it should be
Beyeler only.
I tried this one:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN NAME)-1) FROM OBJ_RESOURCE
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: SUBSTRING FROM FOR is no SQL Server syntax, what's your DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest functions:

```
SUBSTRING(REPLACE(name, '*Deleted*', '' ) FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN REPLACE(name, '*Deleted*', '' ))-1) FROM OBJ_R
```

Comment: thanks a lot i will try this. I thought i can put them one after another