# How can I print the firstname only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

```
SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(name, , '' ) 
  FROM OBJ_R) AS lastname 
   And
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME 
                     FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN NAME)-1) 
                     FROM OBJ_R
```

instead of

```
 Beyeler,Nicole     Nicole
 Müller, Barbara    Barbara
 Ostmann,Heinz     Heinz
```

I tried this one:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME 
  FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN NAME)-1) 
  FROM OBJ_R
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Im using SQL server

Comment: I'd recommend a design change. Store first name and last name in two separate columns instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Substring and Replace in one SQL-Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871140/how-can-i-use-substring-and-replace-in-one-sql-statement)

Comment: This is no different from your previous post about replace/substring.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `CHARINDEX` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT
    name,
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(name,
                    CHARINDEX(',', name) + 1,
                    LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(',', name))) AS first_name
FROM OBJ_R;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: I use `LTRIM` above because your sample data implies that there might be whitespace after the comma, after the last name.  If not, then you may remove it.

Comment: I can use LENGTH